# Why does my python script works in IDLE and when executed from CMD but not from double clicking

Tags: python, csv, crash, execution

I'm struggling to debug this but I'm afraid it's beyond my current understanding.

I created a simple script in python which purpose in life is to take as input a string (copy-pasted from google sheets) and turn it into a csv file that will be fit to upload to google calendar. It's hard-coded to fit the format of our shift plan at work. Suffice to say that exemplary input could be: MSLS-1Comp-offES-1..ES-22. The program then parses the input according to specified rules, prints parsed items as list and finally creates a csv file in a correct format.

Here is the problem:
The program runs perfectly everywhere I try it, except when I try running it by double clicking it on the desktop (Windows10). When running from CMD, IDLE or online, the program works and produces expected results without any errors. Other simple scripts I wrote, run from the desktop no problem. In this particular one, the program opens (as all the others, in python3.9), but at a particular line just exits (again, it doesn't happen when I run this program from the cmd, IDLE or online). I managed to find the place where the program 'crashes' by inserting print functions. It looks to me that for some reason the program exits/crashes on the line `with io.open("shifts.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8-sig") as f:`.

Is it something with the code? Then why does it run ok when run on the same system just using the command prompt? Is it something with how I have python set up on my computer? In which case why do others scripts I wrote run perfectly from the desktop? I'm really confused here. I would be very grateful for any suggestions. Thank you!

Here is the full code:

```
import subprocess
import sys
import io

year = "2021"
month = input("Please enter month in number format (e.g., '07' for June):\n")

shifts = input("Please paste your shifts:\n")

word = ''
shifts_list = []
for char in shifts: # iterate through the string
    word = word + char # add the character to the word
    if(char in ['1','2','3','.']): # check if the character at current iteration is one of the characters in the list
        shifts_list.append(word) # add the word formed by now to the list
        word = '' # re-initialize the word variable to an empty string so as to start the next word
    if (char in ['S'] and word[-2] in ['M']):
        shifts_list.append(word) # add the word formed by now to the list
        word = '' # re-initialize the word variable to an empty string so as to start the next word

print(shifts_list)


headers = "Subject, Start Date, Start Time, End Date, End Time, Description, Private\n"
start_times = ["6:30", "7:30", "6:30", "9:00", "10:00"]
end_times = ["15:00", "16:00", "17:00", "17:30", "18:30"]
subjects = ["Early ", "Office ", "10h ", "Middle ", "Late "]


print(headers)
input("after this point the program exits")
with io.open("shifts.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8-sig") as f:
    f.write(headers)

    for day, shift in enumerate(shifts_list):
        description = shift
        date = str(day+1) + "." + month + "." + year
        if shift == "Int-ES1":
            print(subjects[0] + ', ' + date +', ' + start_times[0] + ', ' + date + ', ' + end_times[0] + ', ' + description + ', ' + "TRUE\n")
            f.write(subjects[0] + ', ' + date +', ' + start_times[0] + ', ' + date + ', ' + end_times[0] + ', ' + description + ', ' + "TRUE\n")

        if shift == "Int-ES2":
            print(subjects[1] + ', ' + date +', ' + start_times[1] + ', ' + date + ', ' + end_times[1] + ', ' + description + ', ' + "TRUE\n")
            f.write(subjects[1] + ', ' + date +', ' + start_times[1] + ', ' + date + ', ' + end_times[1] + ', ' + description + ', ' + "TRUE\n")

        if shift == "IntES3":
            print(subjects[2] + ', ' + date +', ' + start_times[2] + ', ' + date + ', ' + end_times[2] + ', ' + description + ', ' + "TRUE\n")
            f.write(subjects[2] + ', ' + date +', ' + start_times[2] + ', ' + date + ', ' + end_times[2] + ', ' + description + ', ' + "TRUE\n")

        if shift == "MS":
            print(subjects[3] + ', ' + date +', ' + start_times[3] + ', ' + date + ', ' + end_times[3] + ', ' + description + ', ' + "TRUE\n")
            f.write(subjects[3] + ', ' + date +', ' + start_times[3] + ', ' + date + ', ' + end_times[3] + ', ' + description + ', ' + "TRUE\n")

        if shift == "Int-LS1":
            print(subjects[4] + ', ' + date +', ' + start_times[4] + ', ' + date + ', ' + end_times[4] + ', ' + description + ', ' + "TRUE\n")
            f.write(subjects[4] + ', ' + date +', ' + start_times[4] + ', ' + date + ', ' + end_times[4] + ', ' + description + ', ' + "TRUE\n")


print("Your shifts have been successfully saved to a CSV file. You can now import it to your calendar :)")
input("Press enter to exit...")

def open_folder(path):
    if sys.platform == 'darwin':
        subprocess.check_call(['open', '--', path])
    elif sys.platform == 'linux2':
        subprocess.check_call(['gnome-open', '--', path])
    elif sys.platform == 'win64':
        subprocess.check_call(['explorer', path])

open_folder(path=".")  # open current directory
```

Comment: Maybe, your program can't find file shifts.csv and just skip that block of code? Try to use an absolute path here, for example

Comment: What happened when you tried to figure out what the *current working directory* is in each case, depending on how you run the program? (Where on the hard drive do you expect it to look for `shifts.csv`, and why?)

Comment: Try adding `import os; os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))` to the top

Comment: Thank you for you replies :) Martin Evans' line solved it indeed. I will need to study this some more to understand it, but I can see there are some resources online. Thank you so much! <3